# How to pass data to view and Load view into a variable

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to pass `$data` variable to `print` view then I want to pass result of `print` view to a variable (`$myvariable` ), I don't want to show anything to user :

```
$myvariable =  $this->load->view('print' , $data,true);
```

but `$myvariable`  is null and `print` view will load!

**updated**

```
    function makePDF(){

        $pdfFilePath = FCPATH."assests/gifts/test.pdf";
        $data['page_title'] = 'Hello world'; // pass data to the view

        if (file_exists($pdfFilePath) == FALSE)
        {
            ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); // boost the memory limit if it's low <img src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/72x72/1f609.png" alt="" draggable="false" class="emoji">
            $html = $this->printer(212486); // render the view into HTML
            var_dump($html);
            return;
            $this->load->library('pdf');
            $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
            $pdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'|{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822)); // Add a footer for good measure <img src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/72x72/1f609.png" alt="" draggable="false" class="emoji">
            $pdf->WriteHTML($html); // write the HTML into the PDF
            $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F'); // save to file because we can
        }


    }



    function printer( $id = 0  ){

....


        $data =  array ('coupons'=>$coupons  , 'shop'=>$shop , 'details'=>$parent );
        return $this->view('print' , $data,true);



    }
```

Comment: And why would one want to do this?

Comment: To make `pdf ` file .

Comment: does your view is loading properly, if yes then $myvariable should not be null. and one more correction in your code you have written $this->view instead of $this->load->view

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `return` to get your view back, instead, adjust your functions to save the view into a variable and then return that variable. Also, when you say `$myvariable` is NULL, I assume you are referring to the `$html` variable in your UPDATED section?

Firstly, these lines will display your view just because you're dumping out written html and then exiting the function:

```
var_dump($html);
return;
```

So to clean up, I would suggest altering your functions like so:

```
function makePDF(){
    $pdfFilePath = FCPATH."assests/gifts/test.pdf";
    $data['page_title'] = 'Hello world'; // pass data to the view

    if (file_exists($pdfFilePath) == FALSE)
    {
        ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); // boost the memory limit if it's low
        $html = $this->printer(212486); // render the view into HTML

        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
        $pdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'|{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822)); // Add a footer for good measure
        $pdf->WriteHTML($html); // write the HTML into the PDF
        $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F'); // save to file because we can
    }
}
```

and...

```
function printer( $id = 0  ){

    ....

    $data =  array ('coupons'=>$coupons  , 'shop'=>$shop , 'details'=>$parent );
    $return_html = $this->load->view('print' , $data, true);

    return $return_html;

}
```

The biggest difference here is ensuring the view syntax is written correctly from `$this->view('print', $data, true);` to `$this->LOAD->view('print', $data, true);`

Also, for good measure the view return was saved into a variable and returned as that object. I would step these changes one at a time because taking that second step may not be necessary.

Comment: 0k, but there is a problem. I don't want to show `print view ` to user.